# Autocomplete dropdown not rendering on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-select2

I am developing a modal form, where select2 ui is used for an input field with id="location", but the dropdown list seems not to appear only in Safari.

I tested the autocomplete on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Microsoft Edge on different resolutions and the list seems to pop up with no problems. I have no idea why this is happening only in Safari and would be really happy if somebody could help me.

The input field:

```
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group mult_stp_1st_inputs">
        <input id="location" type="text" name="location" class="form-control" placeholder="Напишете град" aria-required="true" value="{{ Auth::check() && Auth::user()->userDetails ? Auth::user()->userDetails->place_of_birth : old('location') }}">
        <div id="location-error" style="display: none; color: red;">* Please select a city from the list. If yours does not appear you can choose the closest city to you.</div>
        @error('location')
            <span class="text-danger">* {{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror 
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code, that handles the autocomplete:

```
var jq331 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

jq331(document).ready(function() {
  var options = []; 
  var cities = [];
  var limit = 10; 
  var timer;

  if (jq331.ui && jq331.ui.autocomplete) {
    console.log("Autocomplete module loaded successfully.");
  } else {
    console.log("Autocomplete module failed to load.");
  }

  var deferred1 = jq331.getJSON("https://energyworld557.com/geonames-all-cities.json", function(data) {
    var tempCities = data.filter(function(city) {
      var population = parseInt(city.population);
      return (city.label_en === "Bulgaria") || (!isNaN(population) && population >= 10000);
    });

    tempCities.forEach(function(city) {
      cities.push({
        name: city.name,
        label_en: city.label_en
      });
    });
  });
  

  var deferred2 = jq331.getJSON("https://energyworld557.com/raw.githubusercontent.com_Kostadin_Places-in-Bulgaria_master_Places-in-Bulgaria.json", function(data) {
    for (var region in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(region)) {
        for (var municipality in data[region]) {
          if (data[region].hasOwnProperty(municipality)) {
            for (var code in data[region][municipality]) {
              if (data[region][municipality].hasOwnProperty(code)) {
                cities.push({
                  name: data[region][municipality][code].name,
                  label_en: municipality
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

jq331.when(deferred1, deferred2).done(function() {
  var locationAutocomplete = jq331('#location').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2
  }).autocomplete('instance');

  var userLocationAutocomplete = jq331('#user-location').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2
  }).autocomplete('instance');

  function updateAutocomplete(value) {
    var filtered = cities.filter(function(city) {
      return city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) === 0;
    });

    options = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(filtered.length, limit); i++) {
      options.push(filtered[i].name + "/" + filtered[i].label_en);
    }
    
    if (locationAutocomplete) {
      locationAutocomplete.option('source', options);
    }

    if (userLocationAutocomplete) {
      userLocationAutocomplete.option('source', options);
    }
  }

  if (jq331('#user-location').length) {
    jq331('#user-location').on('input', function() {
      var value = jq331(this).val();
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        updateAutocomplete(value);
      }, 200);
    });

    jq331('#user-location').on('mousedown', function() {
      if (jq331(this).val().length >= 1 && userLocationAutocomplete && userLocationAutocomplete.element[0].hasAttribute('autocomplete')) {
        userLocationAutocomplete.search();
      }
    });

    jq331('#user-location').on('blur', function() {
      var value = jq331(this).val();
      if (options.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        jq331(this).val('');
      }
    });
  }

  jq331('#location').on('input', function() {
    var value = jq331(this).val();
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      updateAutocomplete(value);
    }, 200);
  });

  jq331('#location').on('mousedown', function() {
    if (jq331(this).val().length >= 1 && locationAutocomplete && locationAutocomplete.element[0].hasAttribute('autocomplete')) {
      locationAutocomplete.search();
    }
  });

  jq331('#location').on('blur', function() {
    var value = jq331(this).val();
    if (options.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      jq331(this).val('');
    }
  });

  jq331('.human-design-modal-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var value = jq331('#location').val();
    if (options.indexOf(value) === -1) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jq331('#location-error').show();
    } else {
      jq331('#location-error').hide();
    }
  });
});
  

  
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve] that includes the Jquery and jQuery UI versions you are using.